# Is there a way to delegate a job to another action in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Suppose we have two models: `Users`, and `Posts`. *These models have many-to-many relationship defined between them* - a user can have many posts, and post can have many editors(users).

When this form is submitted to `PostsController`, it's `store` **action must handle not only the new post's fields, but also it's editors, which seems wrong.** Example:

[image]

```php
public function store()
{
    // creating a post
    $post = Post::create(request()->get('post_fields'));

    // adding editors to the post (this should be done somewhere else)
    $editors = request()->get('editors');
    foreach($editors as $editor){
        $post->editors()->attach($editor->id);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

As I already mentioned, this approach seems wrong and clumsy to me. Because of this I want to **delegate** editors handling task to `PostsEditorsController`, which will be a separate controller dedicated only to `posts-editors` relationship management. So the `store` will now look something like this:

```php
public function store()
{
    // creating a post
    $post = Post::create(request()->get('post_fields'));

    $editors = request()->get('editors');
    PostsEditorsController::doSomething($post, $editors); // <-- just to show what I want to achieve

    return redirect('/');
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this logic to the Post model's save events?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

That way, this logic will call **any time the model is saved**, saving you the fuss of worrying about keeping it synced if you add editing anywhere else in the system.

Comment: That's a good way of solving this problem, but I think that using Controllers to do this job feels more natural. Besides, what would you do in other frameworks where events are not available? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right that it may be a bit awkward to handle controller data with events, but trying to simplify this any further would get a bit ridiculous. You can easily sum this up in one line by doing `$post->sync('editors', $editors->pluck('id'));`, IIRC. That's one line -- not going to get any simpler.

Comment: the question is more about **where** should it be done, rather than **how**. So, does `$post->sync('editors', $editors->pluck('id'));` have to stay in `store` action, or should it go somewhere else? If we had more "side things" to do in `store` method, which is supposed to only store the post data, it would grow really huge. Sorry if I am not being clear enough.

Comment: I'm just a little confused on how this can be improved. Your code is correct. You don't want to duplicate logic, that I understand, but I simply cannot imagine it being any simpler. You could move this to the Model and do `$post->syncEditors($editors)`, then in that check if it's either a Collection of Editors or an array of integers. Alternatively, you might get something out of FormRequests ( https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests ). I just don't see a way to shift locations around at all -- syncing editors is _PRECISELY_ what the business logic of a controller should do.

Comment: What if I want to add/remove editors **after** the post is created. I imagine, that there are two ways of solving this: 1. Create a separate controller and add necessary actions there 2. Just add the actions into the existing controller. Either ways the code of the `addEditor` action will be duplicated, because the exact same code is also contained in the `Post::store` action. That is why I want to make `Post::store` to utilize `addEditor` action. It is not about code simplification, but about making the code DRY

Comment: I would suggest a `$post->syncEditors()` then. I'm not sure it gets much drier than that.